# onListItemClick, can I get the absolute position from 'id'?

Tags: android, listview

I have

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, column));
getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

and

```
public void onListItemClick(
        ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
```

I need to fine the position in column of the clicked item.  Position is no good since the filter is on.  Can I somehow derive the real position from 'id'?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

After you've set up a listview, do a once-through of the entire list, adding all the visible items indexes to an array.  For instance, in a 5 element list, with the 2nd and 4th items not visible, it would look like this:

indexes[0] = 0
indexes[1] = -1
indexes[2] = 1
indexes[3] = -1
indexes[4] = 2

then when you get a position in the onListItemClick, that's just an index in the "indexes" array that returns the real position in the filtered ListView.

Then inside your onListItemClick, just use the position passed as a parameter as a key to look up the position in the filtered list.

EDIT:  SparseArray is overkill.  Offering reasonably easy solution.

Comment: Hi Alex  I was hoping far a simpler solution, but I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use `.getChildCount()` and `.getChildAt()` and then check `.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE` on each to count the number of visible, and check if the clicked item is equal to the current iterrated. There's no straightforward way I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

position in listview is the position of the element in generic object ie list you pass to an array adapter.

Comment: Hi Rakshi   Not with the filter in play.  It will be the relative position in the filtered list. Cliff

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever had good luck with ItemIDs.

Might want to instead pull the data from `View v`.  This view might contain a TextView, which you could use to determine which row the user clicked on.  This won't work if multiple rows can be displayed identically though...

So if that is the case, you are going to have to iterate through the dataset calling `getItemID(int position)` on every element in the adapter.  Store these longs in an array the same size as the dataset, and use the same index on both your `column` dataset and this long ItemID array.

Comment: Hi Edthethird  Well this has some merit.  I was searching through the array and comparing strings, but there are duplicates.  I could use this to sort out the duplicates. Thanks.